# TextView cannot be cast to SeekBar

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

I am experiencing issues relating my textview to my seekbar, and have received the below message as such. I am under the premises that it was due for the following reasons: 1) Trying to store the seekbar values information recorded by the user into parse to be able to retrieve it later. Storing the EditText such as name, age, headline and radiobox such as gender works fine, but its when I include the seek that the application fails to run.

I have tried doing a project clean, and rewording ID with the "right prefix" such as sb for seekbar, and tv for textview.

Below is the logcat message:

```
update logcat posted below
```

Below is the activity code

```
public class ProfileCreation extends Activity {

    private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    FrameLayout layout;
    Button save;
    protected EditText mName;
    protected EditText mAge;
    protected EditText mHeadline;
    protected ImageView mprofilePicture;
    RadioButton male, female;
    String gender;
    RadioButton lmale, lfemale;
    String lgender;
    protected SeekBar seekBarMinimum;
    protected SeekBar seekBarMaximum;
    protected SeekBar seekBarDistance;


    protected Button mConfirm;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_creation);

        RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main); 

        v.requestFocus();

        Parse.initialize(this, "ID", "ID");

        mName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtname);
        mAge = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtage);
        mHeadline = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtheadline);
        mprofilePicture = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
        male = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rimale);
        female = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rifemale);
        lmale = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rlmale);
        lfemale = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rlfemale);
        seekBarMinimum = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbseekBarMinimumAge);
        seekBarMaximum = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbseekBarMaximumAge);
        seekBarDistance = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.tvseekBarDistanceValue);




        mConfirm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnConfirm);
        mConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String name = mName.getText().toString();
                String age = mAge.getText().toString();
                String headline = mHeadline.getText().toString();




                age = age.trim();
                name = name.trim();
                headline = headline.trim();

                if (age.isEmpty() || name.isEmpty() || headline.isEmpty()) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileCreation.this);
                    builder.setMessage(R.string.signup_error_message)
                        .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
                else {
                    // create the new user!
                    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

                    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

                     seekBarMaximum.getProgress();
                     seekBarMinimum.getProgress();
                     seekBarDistance.getProgress();



                    if(male.isChecked())
                        gender = "Male";
                    else
                        gender = "Female";

                    if(lmale.isChecked())
                        lgender = "Male";
                    else
                        lgender = "Female";


                    currentUser.put("Name", name); 
                    currentUser.put("Age", age); 
                    currentUser.put("Headline", headline); 
                    currentUser.put("Gender", gender);
                    currentUser.put("Looking_Gender", lgender);
                    currentUser.put("Minimum_Age", seekBarMinimum);
                    currentUser.put("Maximum_Age", seekBarMaximum);
                    currentUser.put("Maximum_Distance_Age", seekBarDistance);




                    currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                            if (e == null) {
                                // Success!
                                Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileCreation.this, MoodActivity.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                            else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileCreation.this);
                                builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                    .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                dialog.show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });



        SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbseekBarDistance);
        final TextView seekBarValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvseekBarDistanceValue);

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                seekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

        }); // Add this

        Button mcancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        mcancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ProfileCreation.this.startActivity(new Intent(ProfileCreation.this, LoginActivity.class));
            }
        });




        SeekBar seekBarMinimum = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbseekBarMinimumAge);
        final TextView txtMinimum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMinAge);

        seekBarMinimum.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                txtMinimum.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

        }); // Add this

        SeekBar seekBarMaximum = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbseekBarMaximumAge);
        final TextView txtMaximum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMaxAge);

        seekBarMaximum.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                txtMaximum.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

        }); // Add this




        Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPictureSelect);
        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });

    } 

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

            }

        }

        private byte[] readInFile(String path) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            byte[] data = null;
            File file = new File(path);
            InputStream input_stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                    file));
            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            data = new byte[16384]; // 16K
            int bytes_read;
            while ((bytes_read = input_stream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                buffer.write(data, 0, bytes_read);
            }
            input_stream.close();
            return buffer.toByteArray();

        }
    }
```

Below is the layout xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollProfile"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/dark_texture_blue" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="797dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profilePicturePreview"
        android:layout_width="132dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:background="@drawable/border_image"
        android:alpha="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bRemove"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/etxtage"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etxtname"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="#330099"
        android:text="Upload from Facebook"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPictureSelect"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etxtname"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profilePicturePreview"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:onClick="pickPhoto"
        android:text="Select photo from gallery"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:text="Preferred Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Profile Creation"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxtname"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:hint="Please type your name here"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etxtname"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Upload your Profile Picture"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etxtheadline"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/texperience"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rimale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Male"
            android:textColor="#f2f2f2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rifemale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Female"
            android:textColor="#f2f2f2" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sbseekBarDistance"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:progress="50" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etxtheadline"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rlmale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Male"
            android:textColor="#f2f2f2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rlfemale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Female"
            android:textColor="#f2f2f2" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sbseekBarMinimumAge"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:progress="25" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etxtage"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Minimum Age Looking For"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvseekBarDistanceValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvMinAge"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sbseekBarDistance"
        android:text="50"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="Search Distance "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMinAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sbseekBarMinimumAge"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="25"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvMaxAge"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Headline"
        android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvMinAge"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Maximum Age Looking For"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sbseekBarMaximumAge"
        android:layout_width="221dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:progress="50" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMaxAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sbseekBarMaximumAge"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="50"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/conditions"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnConfirm"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:alpha="0.6"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/disclaimer"
        android:textColor="#99CCFF"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnConfirm"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvseekBarDistanceValue"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvseekBarDistanceValue"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="#151B54"
        android:text="Confirm"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxtheadline"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="A quick description of yourself"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="18dp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxtage"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnPictureSelect"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Please type your age here"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnConfirm"
        android:text="Looking for"
        android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texperience"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etxtheadline"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:text="I am a"
        android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


/>

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. All the best.

**Update**

```
Upon resolving the previous, another error related was triggered. I have tried resolving it, but is still experiencing issues. Below is the logcat


 08-13 14:56:24.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1306): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365): Process: com.dooba.beta, PID: 1365
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid type for value: class android.widget.SeekBar
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at com.parse.ParseObject.put(ParseObject.java:2152)
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at com.parse.ParseUser.put(ParseUser.java:315)
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at com.dooba.beta.ProfileCreation$1.onClick(ProfileCreation.java:136)
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Error is here: `seekBarDistance = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.tvseekBarDistanceValue);`. You are not allowed to cast a `TextView` to a `SeekBar`.

Comment: Thank you for identifying the error. I have adjusted the code as such, and this has resolved that issue. However, another similar issue seems to prevail. I have included the new logcat error message under the update section of my initial post. If you could also take a look at it, that would be helpful.

Comment: You might want to post any new issues in a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML has defined `tvseekBarDistanceValue` as a TextView, not a SeekBar. Since you're trying to change a TextView to a SeekBar (which is impossible), you are getting this error.

Based on your XML, I think you want to replace

```
seekBarDistance = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.tvseekBarDistanceValue);
```

with

```
seekBarDistance = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbseekBarDistance);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt resolve. This has helped clarified much, but unfortunately another issue prevails from this fix. I have kindly updated the information under the update section of my initial post. If you could look into it, I would be greatly thankful.

Comment: Sorry I just realized that I added the previous logcat message under my update section. Hence, I have re-updated my update section under my initial post.